# How To Refresh A Grid From Another Form In c# Window Form Application

Tags: c#

I Have A MDI Form As DashBoard There Is 1 DataGrid Control And 1 Submit Button After Submit Button Form 2 Is Open I Have To Write A Code On Form 2 And Refresh a Dashboards Grid

Comment: Give some more detail or share your code what you have tried so far

Comment: // DashBoard objDashBoard = new DashBoard();
// objDashBoard.refreshgrid();

Comment: public void RefreshDgv()
        {
            //dgvProductList.DataSource = null;
            //dgvProductList.Refresh();
            dgvProductList.Rows.Clear();

            
        }

Comment: You should point out your platform. Anyway, no matter which platform, there should have some associated property like `Owner` in `form2` which is `form1` instance. You can access dashboard by it. If there isn't anything like that. Pass the form1(or dashboard) instance yourself when popup.

Comment: You should edit your post to add code instead of posting them in a comment. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to learn how to use code block.

Answer (score 2):

you can create a function in current form like

```
class form1{
...
..
   public refreshGrid(){
   .....
   ....
   }
}
```

and you can call this from another form like

```
class form2{

       public myFun(){
       ......  
       ......
       from1 obj = new form1();
       obj.refreshGrid();
       }

}
```

Comment: Yes I Have Already Tried This One But Grid Can Not Be Refresged Gaurav shukla

Comment: @Yog include your code in your question. Then we can see why it can not be refreshed